# How do you set the ends of objects to be side by side while transforming the object length?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am posting an issue that was not addressed on Blender beginners courses. I'm using Blender 2.90.1 and what I want to achieve is to set one end of multiple objects to be side by side so no object sticks out when you  view them on the xy plane.

So far, I have only managed to set objects side by side with one end sticking out as shown in the areas of the image enclosed in orange boxes and could not achieve the objective with the Scaling tool because the tool scales objects from the center.

Please someone help me work out how the ends can be flat with no end sticking out.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to move/align the objects. wholesale. or stretch one end of them?

Comment: I'd like to stretch either of the objects to align their ends.